# Showing html from string in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

How to show html from json string in html page using  js 
[image]

Code so far :

```
function RequestNoteItem(props) {
    return(
        <li className={ props.isAdmin == 1 ? "out" : "in"} >
            <div className="message" style={props.isAdmin==1 ?   {marginRight: 0} : {marginLeft: 0} }>
                <span className="arrow"> </span>
                <a  href="#" className="name"> {props.username} </a>
                <a onClick={props.onDelete} id={props.id}  style={{color:'red'}} className={ props.isAdmin == 1 ? "pull-left" : "pull-right"}>✖</a>

                <span className="datetime"> {props.time}</span>
                <span className="body"  style={{maxWidth:900+'px'}}> {props.content } </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

JSON :

```
note: "<a href=/system/web/email//request-packagedefault/index?id=42 >Email</a> sent to Karim with some attachments and follwing packages: - <a href=/system/web/request/request-package?id=1 >wefwef</a>- <a href=/system/web/request/request-package?id=2 >w ferg</a>- <a href=/system/web/request/request-package?id=3 >rthrth</a>- <a href=/system/web/request/request-package?id=4 >ewrgwergerg</a>",
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have.

Comment: @spirift I am working with react js this is the component that contain the view above in photo

Comment: What is the JSON string and how do you want the output to look like

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I updated my question , this is the string that I get from json I want to show html links

Comment: The string that you get is not JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property to render `html` string,

From [Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React's replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM.

Check this example:

```js
var string = "<a href='#'>abc</a>";

class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
  
    return(
      <div>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: string   }}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```